# C - join arrays

Tags: c, arrays, join

why can't i use Join? it doesn't have the 4 (e) from set B... why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZEOF_A 6
#define SIZEOF_B 6

typedef enum {
        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
} set;

void dispSet(set numbers[], int size_numbers) {
  int i;
  printf("[ ");
  for (i = 0; i < size_numbers-1; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", numbers[i]);
  }
  printf("%d ]", numbers[size_numbers-1]);
  printf("\n");
}

int in_arr(int A, set B[], int B_size) {
    int res = 0;
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < B_size; counter++) {
        if (A == B[counter]) {
            res = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int arr_in_arr(set smaller[], int smaller_size, set bigger[], int bigger_size) {
    int res = 1;
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < smaller_size; counter++) {
        if (in_arr(smaller[counter], bigger, bigger_size)) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            res = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int size_c(set arr1[], int arr1_size, set arr2[], int arr2_size) {
    int i;
    int newsize = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++) {
        if (!in_arr(arr1[i], arr2, arr2_size)) {
            newsize++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < arr2_size; i++) newsize++;
    printf("\nSIZE OF C: %d\n", newsize);
    return newsize;
}

int Join(set arr1[], int arr1_size, set arr2[], int arr2_size, set arr3[], int arr3_size) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++) {
        arr3[i] = arr1[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < arr2_size; i++) {
        j = i+arr2_size;
        if (!in_arr(arr2[i], arr3, arr3_size)) {
            arr3[j] = arr2[i];
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    set A[SIZEOF_A] = {c, d, f, a, b, j};
    set B[SIZEOF_B] = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
    int SIZEOF_C = size_c(A, SIZEOF_A, B, SIZEOF_B);
    int counter;
    printf("For the sets,\n");
    printf("A: ");
    dispSet(A, SIZEOF_A);
    printf("B: ");
    dispSet(B, SIZEOF_B);
    printf("C: ");
    set C[SIZEOF_C];
    Join(A, SIZEOF_A, B, SIZEOF_B, C, SIZEOF_C);
    dispSet(C, SIZEOF_C);
    printf("%s\n", (arr_in_arr(A, SIZEOF_A, B, SIZEOF_B) == 1)?"B contains A":"B does not contain A");
}
```

Comment: Didn't look further than `in_arr`. You are missing the initialization for `res`.

Comment: okay i added the initialization, compiled, and all that changed was the addition of `0` to `C`

Comment: please turn on warnings on your compiler and fix what it reports. Edit this when you've fixed them (for example, `res` is not initialized in `in_arr` if the value is not found, `printf("", smaller[counter]);` isn't valid)

Comment: thats what `size_c` is for, no?

Comment: and how do you turn on compiler warnings?

Comment: i initialized `res` and used a `continue` statement...now what?

Comment: Could you give more details on what is the exact problem from your side? What do you mean by "can't use join"? Do you have any error message or something else?

Comment: all i get is `ISO C90 forbids variable-size array 'C'` and also that Join() doesn't function correctly: the `4` (e) from B is not present in `C`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the assignment indexing in the second loop of the `Join()` function:

```
int Join(set arr1[], int arr1_size, set arr2[], int arr2_size, set arr3[], int arr3_size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++)
        arr3[i] = arr1[i];
    for (i = 0; i < arr2_size; i++)
    {
        if (!in_arr(arr2[i], arr3, arr3_size))
            arr3[i+arr1_size] = arr2[i];
    }
}
```

You need to keep a counter that progresses through the `arr3` array properly even when `i` is reset to zero (and some of the `i` values are not added).  The function is declared to return a value but does not do so - another bug.  Either return the actual size of the result array (shown below) or declare the function to return `void`.  Since the returned value is not used, the second option might be better. This might do the job:

```
int Join(set arr1[], int arr1_size, set arr2[], int arr2_size, set arr3[], int arr3_size)
{
    int i;
    int k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++)
        arr3[k++] = arr1[i];
    for (i = 0; i < arr2_size; i++)
    {
        if (!in_arr(arr2[i], arr3, arr3_size))
            arr3[k++] = arr2[i];
    }
    assert(k <= arr3_size);
    return k;
}
```

One minor (performance rather than correctness) issue:

```
int newsize = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++) 
{
    if (!in_arr(arr1[i], arr2, arr2_size)) 
        newsize++;
}
for (i = 0; i < arr2_size; i++) 
    newsize++;
```

The second loop can be written more succinctly as:

```
newsize += arr2_size;
```

Or, indeed, you could initialize `newsize = arr2_size;` and then count the extras.

```
int newsize = arr2_size;
for (i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++) 
{
    if (!in_arr(arr1[i], arr2, arr2_size)) 
        newsize++;
}
```

There's a dubious `printf()` statement in `arr_in_arr()`:

```
int arr_in_arr(set smaller[], int smaller_size, set bigger[], int bigger_size)
{
    int res = 1;
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < smaller_size; counter++)
    {
        if (in_arr(smaller[counter], bigger, bigger_size))
            printf("%d ", smaller[counter]);
        else
        {
            res = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Either, it should have '`%d`' in the format string or the conditional should be inverted and the whole function simplified:

```
int arr_in_arr(set smaller[], int smaller_size, set bigger[], int bigger_size)
{
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < smaller_size; counter++)
    {
        if (!in_arr(smaller[counter], bigger, bigger_size))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The variable `counter` in `main()` is not used.

---

Looked at structurally, your 'set' abstraction is not great; you have to pass an array and a size every time you call a function.  Also, you can have a variable `set x;` which contains a single element (rather than a set).  You could improve this with a structure, but that might get you into too much memory allocation for the time being.

There is also no code to ensure that the sets contain no duplicates.  That is, if you defined a set:

```
set D[] = { a, c, a, d };
```

The result set of the `Join()` operation where this was the left (first) operand would contain two elements `a` in the output.  Incidentally, the `Join()` operation could also be regarded as a set union, `a ∪ b`.

---

I ended up with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define SIZEOF_A 6
#define SIZEOF_B 6

typedef enum
{
        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
} set;

static void dispSet(set numbers[], int size_numbers)
{
    int i;
    printf("[ ");
    for (i = 0; i < size_numbers-1; i++)
        printf("%d, ", numbers[i]);
    printf("%d ]", numbers[size_numbers-1]);
    printf("\n");
}

static int in_arr(set A, set B[], int B_size)
{
    int res = 0;  // XXX: uninitialized
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < B_size; counter++)
    {
        if (A == B[counter])
        {
            res = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

static int arr_in_arr(set smaller[], int smaller_size, set bigger[], int bigger_size)
{
    int counter;  // XXX: simplified
    for (counter = 0; counter < smaller_size; counter++)
    {
        if (!in_arr(smaller[counter], bigger, bigger_size))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

static int size_c(set arr1[], int arr1_size, set arr2[], int arr2_size)
{
    int i;
    int newsize = arr2_size;    // XXX: compacted
    for (i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++)
    {
        if (!in_arr(arr1[i], arr2, arr2_size))
            newsize++;
    }
    printf("\nSIZE OF C: %d\n", newsize);
    return newsize;
}

static int Join(set arr1[], int arr1_size, set arr2[], int arr2_size, set arr3[], int arr3_size)
{
    int i;
    int k;  // XXX: fixed
    for (i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++)
        arr3[k++] = arr1[i];
    for (i = 0; i < arr2_size; i++)
    {
        if (!in_arr(arr2[i], arr3, arr3_size))
            arr3[k++] = arr2[i];
    }
    assert(k <= arr3_size);
    return k;
}

int main(void)
{
    set A[SIZEOF_A] = {c, d, f, a, b, j};
    set B[SIZEOF_B] = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
    int SIZEOF_C = size_c(A, SIZEOF_A, B, SIZEOF_B);
    printf("For the sets,\n");
    printf("A: ");
    dispSet(A, SIZEOF_A);
    printf("B: ");
    dispSet(B, SIZEOF_B);
    printf("C: ");
    set C[SIZEOF_C];
    Join(A, SIZEOF_A, B, SIZEOF_B, C, SIZEOF_C);
    dispSet(C, SIZEOF_C);
    printf("%s\n", (arr_in_arr(A, SIZEOF_A, B, SIZEOF_B) == 1)?"B contains A":"B does not contain A");
}
```

The functions are made static because there is no other file using them nor any header declaring them (and that shuts up the compiler warnings from `-Wmissing-prototypes`).
I compiled it (on MacOS X 10.6.7 using Apple's GCC 4.2.1) using:

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes join.c -o join
```

The output is:

```
SIZE OF C: 7
For the sets,
A: [ 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 9 ]
B: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
C: [ 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 9, 4 ]
B does not contain A
```

Answer (score 3):

your issue is that you are using i to place the new element into array 3 and access the elements from array 2. Make a new variable say j that is used to access the elements from array 3.

This worked for me.

```
int Join(set arr1[], int arr1_size, set arr2[], int arr2_size, set arr3[], int arr3_size) {
    int i;
    int j = 0; /*NEW VARIABLE*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++) {
        arr3[i] = arr1[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arr2_size; i++) {
        if (!in_arr(arr2[i], arr3, arr3_size)) {
            arr3[j+arr1_size] = arr2[i]; /*USE j TO ADD ELEMENT TO arr3*/
        j++; /*INCREMENT EACH TIME THIS IS DONE*/
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's run through the code at the point where join tries to but `e` into the union:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr2_size; i++) {
    if (!in_arr(arr2[i], arr3, arr3_size)) {
        arr3[i+arr1_size] = arr2[i];
    }
}
```

In this case, the index of `e` in `arr2` is equal to 4. It's not in `arr3`, so we try to put it in `arr3` at position `i+arr1_size`. Here's the problem - `i+arr1_size` is 6+4, or 10. `size_c` looks correct, so `arr3_size` ought to be 7. (--> 7 is less than 10)

So the code *is* recognizing that `e` isn't in `arr3` yet, and it *is* attempting to put it in `arr3`, but it fails in this regard because the *index at which it tries to place e is outside the bounds of the array*.

You'll have to keep track of the number of elements in `arr3` separately.

[edit]Ah, I guess this is pretty much what Yoel was talking about, I didn't read it very well the first time[/edit]